# C++ lambda ´this´ pointer invalidation after move operation

Tags: c++, lambda, move

I have the following (simplified) code in my current project:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>


class Test{

public:

    Test() = default;
    Test(const Test& other) = delete;
    Test& operator=(const Test& other) = delete;
    Test(Test&& other) = default;
    Test& operator=(Test&& other) = default;



    void setFunction(){
       lambda = [this](){
           a = 2;
       };
    }  

    int callAndReturn(){
       lambda();
       return a;
    }

private:
    std::function<void()> lambda; 
    int a = 50;
};


int main()
{
  Test t;
  t.setFunction();
  std::vector<Test> elements;
  elements.push_back(std::move(t));
  std::cout << elements[0].callAndReturn() << std::endl;
}
```

When I run it, the value 50 is printed instead of the expected value 2. I suppose this happens because the lambda function captures the current `this` pointer. After the move operation the `this` pointer changes and the function writes to the wrong `a`.

**Now my question is:** Is there a way to change the lambda's captured reference to the new `Test` so that the value 2 is printed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is not to capture `this` at all. Instead, change your captured function type to accept it. And use a pointer to member (captured by value) for the indirect access to `a`.

```
std::function<void(Test*)> lambda; 

void setFunction(){
   auto a = &Test::a;
   lambda = [=](Test *t){
       (t->*a) = 2;
   };
}  

int callAndReturn(){
   lambda(this);
   return a;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://ideone.com/DzXMQy)</kbd>

---

As Galik noted, if you only need to access a single hard-coded member, then you don't even need that pointer to member. Thus the lambda can be capture-less:

```
void setFunction(){
   lambda = [](Test *t){
       t->a = 2;
   };
}
```

Comment: Can't you just do `t->a = 2;` and forget about the member pointer?

Comment: @Galik - I don't know why, but I got the impression the OP wanted the member to not be hardcoded. I'll add that in of course, since a capture-less lambda is even simpler as you noted.

Comment: It seems to me the basic problem is the lambda capturing `this` pointer which does not get updated with the *move*. By passing in the current `this` pointer as a parameter the lambda always works on the correct object.

Comment: @Galik - Well, yes. That's the general theme of the answer either way. Both versions of the lambda address *that*. I just went over- generic and made the member access indirect as well, instead of keeping it simple first. Oh well.